# Architecture questions suitable for SO?

Tags: discussion

I'm a fairly new user to stack exchange, only using it for the last few days. I have posted a number of questions, mainly about software architecture.

Some examples:

1. I did some research, mentioned what I would like to achieve and what I think would be a good solution and asked for best practice approach on this.
2. Some others were of the sort of nature of "does technology x have disadvantages over technology y".
3. And others were along the lines of "This is what I found out - am I on the right track?".

Unfortunately they have all been voted down or put on hold as either too broad or opinion based. I don't have many examples, because I removed these posts as they don't seem to add value to other users - just [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801021/rest-and-doctrine-orm).

I'm unsure how to ask architecture questions on SO. Is it the wrong forum for it, because it doesn't involve code and therefore will always be broad? Any tips for formulating these sort of questions?

Thank you in advance - please don't vote down this post as "too broad" :)

Comment: In regards to my 2) - I found this on the [FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic_ . Interesting... it seems it would be off topic even that I don't ask for opinion but explicitly for (dis)advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also fairly new to answering and asking questions on the network. But from what I found I think, [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be a better place to ask these questions. Its description says:

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.

Conceptual questions don't necessarily have code as is the case with your queries. Hence I feel that would be a better place to ask such questions. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: You are right, it seems they do belong to Programmers Stack Exchange. I will post architecture question there in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @phpPhil this guidance at Programmers may be helpful if you decide to post over there:  **[Green fields, blue skys, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Thanks, that's great. Will have a read. Blue sky-y, green fieldy... lol.